# How do I sync two ubuntu folders which are in different servers configured in aws?

Tags: linux, remote, synchronization

I have set up 2 ubuntu instances in aws. How do I sync /usr/ubuntu in both the machines?

Comment: The question that is "duplicate" is now about Ubuntu instances in AWS per se...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rsync` command to sync two directories, e.g:

```
rsync -avzhe "ssh -i yourkey.pem" /usr/ubuntu ubuntu@ec2ip:/usr/ubuntu
```

Comment: The user in Ubuntu is "ubuntu" and not root.  You should add double quotes around the ssh up to the pem file.

Comment: rsync -avzhe "ssh -i mypemfile.pem" /home/ubuntu/bin/ ubuntu@ip-1-1-1-1.ec2.internal:/home/ubuntu/bin/   (make sure ssh is set up, using internal host IPs, internal host IPs are added to the security group)

Answer (score 0):

This question has at least two answers.

If you need periodically sync your folders, you can use `rsync`.

If you need persistent sync and `/usr/ubuntu` is distinguished disk partition, then you can use `DRBD`. It's like Net-RAID. Describe and documentation about `DRBD` - [DRBD official site](https://docs.linbit.com).

Answer (score 0):

Set up one of the instances as an NFS server that exports the directory for the other instance to mount.